# Como usar corretamente a função glVertexAttribPointer() para atributos repetidos

Tags: c++, opengl

Olá! Estou tentando renderizar um cubo **todo vermelho**, porém não queria especificar a cor para todos os vértices afim de economizar espaço. Por exemplo, faríamos assim da maneira tradicional:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
     // Position          // Normal     // Color
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint cubeVAO, cubeVBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Position
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// Normal
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// Color
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Porém os vértices contém o atributo `color` repetido.
A questão é: há alguma maneira de especificar a mesma cor para todos os veŕtices sem que haja repetição da mesma no array?

Comment: Ao invés de ter um `attribute` cor, crie um `uniform` cor e inicialize-o com a cor que vc quer antes de invocar alguma função `draw`